# GroovyAST add generic field at compile time

Tags: generics, groovy, abstract-syntax-tree, bytecode, groovyc

I want to add a generic field to some classes at compile time. To this objective, I was implement my own AST annotation and transformation classes by following the official [documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#developing-ast-xforms) and annotate desired classes with AST annotation.

But I am getting this error at compile time:

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
>   /home/.../groovy/Sample.groovy: -1: A transform used a generics containing ClassNode java.util.HashSet  for the field x directly. You are not supposed to do this. Please create a new ClassNode referring to the old ClassNode and use the new ClassNode instead of the old one. Otherwise the compiler will create wrong descriptors and a potential NullPointerException in TypeResolver in the OpenJDK. If this is not your own doing, please report this bug to the writer of the transform.
>    @ line -1, column -1.

Have I made a mistake?

**Sample codes**

For example, suppose I want to add a `HashSet<Long>` field, named `x`, to every class annotated by `MyAST` annotation.

My AST annotation class:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@GroovyASTTransformationClass(classes = [MyASTTransformation.class])
public @interface MyAST {
}
```

My AST transformation class:

```
@CompileStatic
@GroovyASTTransformation(phase = CompilePhase.SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS)
public class MyASTTransformation implements ASTTransformation {

@Override
public void visit(ASTNode[] nodes, SourceUnit sourceUnit) {
     ClassNode clazz = (ClassNode) nodes[1];
     ClassNode longHashSetClass = new ClassNode(HashSet.class);
     longHashSetClass.setGenericsTypes([new GenericsType(new ClassNode(Long.class))] as GenericsType[]);
     FieldNode field = new FieldNode("x", FieldNode.ACC_PRIVATE, longHashSetClass, clazz, new ConstantExpression(null));
     clazz.addField(field);
 }
}
```

Sample annotated class:

```
@MyAST
public class Sample {
}
```

**Note**

When I eliminate the line `longHashSetClass.setGenericsTypes([new GenericsType(new ClassNode(Long.class))] as GenericsType[]);`, everything is OK but type of `x` is `HashSet` instead of `HashSet<Long>` at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `ClassHelper` or `GenericUtils` in order to create a ClassNode :

```
import static org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassHelper.make
import static org.codehaus.groovy.ast.tools.GenericsUtils.makeClassSafeWithGenerics

...

ClassNode hashSet = makeClassSafeWithGenerics(HashSet, make(Long))
```

Comment: Thank you. It works but if I change `make(HashSet)` to `new ClassNode(HashSet)` I'm getting an error. What's different between them?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know, but ClassNode shouldn't be instanciated directly. these methods handle caching, aliasing and others things necessary when generating bytecodes.